# Convert "stopwatch" time to hourly

Tags: javascript

I have a stopwatch timer built in JS that counts up from 0 using hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.  Currently when the user hits the stop button the value from the timer is appended to a hidden input element for form submission.  I need to convert whatever the time is to just hourly to where it is appended to that hidden input. So right now if my clock is stopped at 25 minutes and 00 seconds, the value in the input is 00:25:00, I would like it to convert the time to something like .25 (for hours)

For example, for 30 minutes the value appended to my hidden input would be .5, for 45 minutes it would be .75, so on and so fourth.

Here is the stopwatch script, the Stop function is where the value is appended to our hidden input, just need to make sure it is converted to hourly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var clsStopwatch = function () {

      var startAt = 0;
      var lapTime = 0;

      var now = function () {
          return (new Date()).getTime();
      };

      this.start = function () {
          startAt = startAt ? startAt : now();
      };

      this.stop = function () {
          lapTime = startAt ? lapTime + now() - startAt : lapTime;
          startAt = 0;
      };

      this.time = function () {
          return lapTime + (startAt ? now() - startAt : 0);
      };
      };

      var x = new clsStopwatch();
      var $time;
      var clocktimer;

      function pad(num, size) {
      var s = "0000" + num;
      return s.substr(s.length - size);
      }

      function formatTime(time) {
      var h = m = s = ms = 0;
      var newTime = '';

      h = Math.floor(time / (3600 * 1000));
      time = time % (3600 * 1000);
      m = Math.floor(time / (60 * 1000));
      time = time % (60 * 1000);
      s = Math.floor(time / 1000);
      ms = time % 1000;

      newTime = pad(h, 2) + ':' + pad(m, 2) + ':' + pad(s, 2);
      //newTime = pad(h, 2) + ':' + pad(m, 2) + ':' + pad(s, 2) + ':' + pad(ms, 2);
      return newTime;
      }

      function show() {
      $time = document.getElementById('time');
      update();
      }

      function update() {
      $time.innerHTML = formatTime(x.time());
      }

      function start() {
      clocktimer = setInterval("update()", 1);
      x.start();
      }

      function stop() {
      x.stop();
      document.getElementById('counter').value = formatTime(x.time());
      clearInterval(clocktimer);
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: Just divide the number of minutes by 60?

Comment: I need to account for seconds as well. The API I am sending the info to requests hourly format and is essentially going to be used as a project task timer so any little bit helps :)  I just suck at math..

Comment: Well a second is 1/3600 of an hour.

Comment: can display one format and send another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you need, this is your solution:

```
function millisecondsToHours(amountMS) {
    return amountMS / 3600000;
}
```